# Sort data in alternate manner

Tags: sql

I have below table

```
EID Ename   Gender
1   A   M
2   B   M
3   C   F
4   D   M
5   E   F
6   F   F
7   G   F
8   H   M
```

Need to sort it like below

```
EID Ename   Gender
1   A   M
3   C   F
2   B   M
5   E   F
4   D   M
6   F   F
8   H   M
7   G   F
```

Comment: Do you need alternate id or alternate gender? Which DBMS you are using?

Comment: "Need to sort it like below" is no use without explaining why, i.e. what logical basis of sorting that reflects.

Answer (score 2):

One option, using `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Gender ORDER BY EID) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    EID, Ename, Gender
FROM cte
ORDER BY
    rn,
    CASE WHEN Gender = 'M' THEN 0 ELSE 1 END;
```

Note that we may need *two* sorting levels to ensure that male entries appear before female entries (not required for the particular data yoy showed though).

Answer (score 1):

Try this..

```
  ; with cte as (
   select row_number() over (partition by gender order by Eid) as Slno, * from table)
   select EID, Ename,   Gender from cte order by slno
```

Answer (score 0):

Without window functions, this will work in any rdbms:

```
select t.eid, t.ename, t.gender
from tablename t  
order by 
  (select count(*) from tablename where gender = t.gender and eid < t.eid), 
  t.gender desc
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6c01ec7af744fdc2dbcaba10f37ddfaa).
Results:

```
> eid | ename | gender
> --: | :---- | :-----
>   1 | A     | M     
>   3 | C     | F     
>   2 | B     | M     
>   5 | E     | F     
>   4 | D     | M     
>   6 | F     | F     
>   8 | H     | M     
>   7 | G     | F
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions directly in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from t
order by row_number() over (partition by gender order by eid),
         gender desc,
         eid;
```

Comment: You forgot to include ORDER BY Clause in row_number() function.

Comment: This meant a lot.